# Why doesn't my Scanner work with 2 different if statements?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

New to Java here. I made the following simple code that asks the user to choose between option 1 or 2. If the selected option is 1, then it should print "You said hi", which it works well, also if selected option is 2, it should prints "you said goodbye" which it doesn't, Am I missing something here? Maybe the If statement is wrong?

the Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please type 1 to say hi");
    System.out.println("Please type 2 to say goodbye");

    if (input.nextInt() == 1) {
        System.out.println("You said hi");
    } else if (input.nextInt() == 2) {
        System.out.println("you said goodbye");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are asking the user twice to input. So u have to input numbers twice. Which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Every time you call `nextInt()` it stops to wait for an `int`. Here you want to compare a single `int` from the user with one ***or*** two. Save the `int` you get from the user. Like,

```
int v = input.nextInt();
if (v == 1) {
    System.out.println("You said hi");
} else if (v == 2) {
    System.out.println("you said goodbye");
}
```

Comment: I see, I get it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Every time you call `nextInt()` on your scanner, input is being consumed. So in your case, when the `else if` condition is checked, the next input is consumed, not the previous one compared. You need to cache your scanner's state:

```java
int answer = input.nextInt();
if (answer == 1) {
    System.out.println("You said hi");
} else if (answer == 2) {
    System.out.println("you said goodbye")
}
```

For your specific case, converting to a `switch` statement would be another option, which evaluates its operand only once:

```java
switch (input.nextInt()) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("You said hi");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("you said goodbye")
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every call to `input.nextInt()` will wait for the new key from input(here it is the user input).

the `input.nextInt() == 1` will wait for the user input.

If it is validates to `true`, the thread will successfully execute `System.out.println("You said hi")`.
Else if it validates to `false`, it will execute the condition in the `input.nextInt() ==2` where the thread will keep waiting for the next input from the user because of the `input.nextInt()`.

If you wish to get input from user only once, execute `input.nextInt()` only once and store it in a variable and run cases against it. Like,

```
// input from user
int selection = input.getInt();

if (selection == 1) {
    System.out.println("the user entered 1");
}
else if (selection == 2) {
    System.out.println("the user entered 2");
}
```

Comment: Might want to add a proposal of how to solve this issue to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Please get input first then check it. (**Don't get input in condition statement**).

Your edited code is as follows:

- Added one line (`int selectedOption = input.nextInt()`)
- edit condition statement (`selectedOption == 1` and `selectedOption == 2`)

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Please type 1 to say hi");
      System.out.println("Please type 2 to say goodbye");

      //Get input
      int selectedOption = input.nextInt() ;

      //Check 
      if (selectedOption == 1) {
          System.out.println("You said hi");
      } else if (selectedOption == 2) {
          System.out.println("you said goodbye");
      }
  }
  ```